# Can I use Thread in Timer?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

this code starts with start button, but this code is used if radiobutton countdown is selected, when the countdown is at 0 the second Frame appears and should change colors by the speed that user entered called "brzinaTreperenja2"(the object that is converted to int and then multiplied by 1000 for miliseconds) with my color red. Blinking does happen when I don't have the second actionListener and the blinking works with speed of 1 second, but when I do, the program freezes. Can you help me with this?

```
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(countdown.isSelected()){

        final Timer p = new Timer();
        display.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD,25));
        display.setBounds(150,75,120,20);
        p.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        int i = Integer.parseInt(odbrojavanje.getText());
        @Override
        public void run(){
        display.setText(""+(i--));
        if(i<0){
            p.cancel();
            drugi.setVisible(true);
            Thread t = new Thread();
            while(true){
                ActionListener al3 = new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent h){
            drugi.getContentPane().setBackground(boja.getBackground());
                try {
                    t.sleep(brzinaTreperenja2);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PrviProzor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            drugi.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
                try {
                    t.sleep(brzinaTreperenja2);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PrviProzor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            };
                javax.swing.Timer p = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, al3);
                p.start();
            }
        }
        }
        },0,1000);
    }
    }
});`
```

Comment: Please add the code in your question, do not post a link to it.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Your code is flouting Swing threading rules:

- You're making Swing calls from background threads, and this is dangerous to do and can cause exceptions to be thrown unpredictably.
- You're using a `java.uti.Timer`, and should be using a `javax.swing.Timer` since the latter's repeated code runs on the Swing event thread.
- You have `while (true)` loops that don't belong. The timer takes over the function of a loop.
- You're repeatedly creating and starting a Swing timer from within a while loop -- why?

For example the following code uses a JSlider to set the blink frequency and a check box to start/stop a Swing Timer that blinks the background color of the main JPanel:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BlinkEg extends JPanel {
    public static final Color COLOR = Color.RED;
    private JSlider slider = new JSlider(100, 1000, 500);
    private JCheckBox blinkBox = new JCheckBox("Blink");
    private Timer timer = new Timer(slider.getValue(), new TimerListener());

    public BlinkEg() {
        slider.setOpaque(false);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(200);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(blinkBox);
        bottomPanel.setOpaque(false);

        blinkBox.setOpaque(false);
        blinkBox.addItemListener(evt -> {
            if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                timer.start();
            } else {
                timer.stop();
                setBackground(null);
            }
        });

        slider.addChangeListener(evt -> {
            int value = slider.getValue();
            timer.setDelay(value);
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(slider);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        private boolean drawColor = false;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color color = drawColor ? null : COLOR;
            BlinkEg.this.setBackground(color);
            drawColor = !drawColor;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        BlinkEg mainPanel = new BlinkEg();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BlinkEg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Note that to change the timing of the Swing Timer, simply call its `setDelay(...)` method:

```
// timer changed to rate set by JSlider:
slider.addChangeListener(evt -> {
    int value = slider.getValue();
    timer.setDelay(value);
});
```

To start and stop the blinking, simply start and stop the Timer:

```
// timer start and stopped based on JCheckBox state
blinkBox.addItemListener(evt -> {
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        timer.start();
    } else {
        timer.stop();
        setBackground(null);  // so always stops with baseline color
    }
});
```

The Swing Timer uses an ActionListener that uses a boolean to decide what color to set the background to, then swaps the value of the boolean

```
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    private boolean drawColor = false;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // choose color based on the state of drawColor
        Color color = drawColor ? null : COLOR;
        BlinkEg.this.setBackground(color);

        drawColor = !drawColor; // now toggle drawColor's boolean value
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to change the speed of the blinking background, and I put a Thread to sleep for  a number of seconds that the  user picks, don't actually know how to write this code

Comment: I said in the question when I don't have a second actionListener the code works but it doesn't blink in the speed that the user picked, it blinks every second

Comment: @Jovaaa: You're grossly over-complicating things and again are running afoul of Swing threading rules. See edit to answer regarding changing timer speed.